# CDI環境にてUtilクラスを作成する場合はstaticクラス?ApplicationScoped?

Tags: java-ee

CDI環境にてUtilクラスを作成する場合は下記1～3どれがベストでしょうか？
性能面や利便性（JUnitとの相性）等考えておりますが、どちらが良いか答えが出ません。

1. staticクラス
　2. ApplicationScopedなクラス
　3. 上記以外

Comment: 普通はstaticクラスでいいと思います。それで何か不都合があれば、後でApplicationScopedなり他の手段なりに変えればいいのでは？ YAGNIという考え方ですね。

Answer (score 0):

「Utilクラス」が何を指すかによりますが、状態（可変なインスタンス変数）を持たないのであれば、「1.」でいいように思います。

ユーティリティクラス（[Apache Commons Lang](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang)のような）には、状態に依存しない共通の処理をstaticメソッドだけで実装することが一般的だと思います（状態を持たない）。

`@ApplicationScoped`は、ドロップダウンリストの値のようにアプリケーションのユーザー全体で共有する状態を保持するために、使用します。

選択の基準はそのあたりかなぁと思います。利便性という観点では、多くの場合、コンテナなどの前提ソフトウェアを必要とせず、扱えるユーティリティクラスの方がいいのではないでしょうか。性能面への影響は、1～3のどの選択肢にするかで大きく変わることは無いように思います（実装次第）。